# What is the significance of God positioning his throne above the earth?

Tags: earth, throne, position

The Book of Isaiah 40:22 provides information on where God's throne is, in proximity to the earth.

**Isaiah 40:22**

> It is he who sits above the circle of the earth

This verse gives us information on where God's throne is because God sits on a throne but that throne is above the circle of the earth according to Prophet Isaiah. The verse is also accurate in that it validates the shape of the earth as proposed by science as being a circle or an ellipse(it is a sphere). Is there any significance why God decided to position his throne close to the earth given how big the universe is?

Since God is everywhere in the universe at all times then establishing his throne in some other place wouldn't have made a difference,  why did he decide to position his throne close to the earth? Was it because he needed to be close to his creation?